# How to count the occurrence of the spaces and any ascii characters in a string?

Tags: c++

I made this code to count the occurrence of each character in a string but it don't count the spaces or any Extended ASCII characters ... Any idea ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
std::string input = "slowly";

std::map<char, int> occurrences;

for (std::string::iterator character = input.begin(); character != input.end(); character++)
{
    occurrences[*character] += 1;
}

for (std::map<char, int>::iterator entry = occurrences.begin(); entry != occurrences.end(); entry++)
{
    std::cout << entry->first << '=' << entry->second << std::endl;
}
}
```

And if there's any faster algorithm to deal with a large amount of characters to get the same results i would be thankful ??

Comment: Well, you could use an array of counts, with `127` entries, then index directly into it. [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is usually a better "default" associative container that `std::map`. (I'm also not a fan of [`std::endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html).)

Comment: it does count spaces and special characters.

Comment: First, you could do it in parallel if you have very large strings. Second, I suggest using a `std::array<std::size_t, 256u>` as the type of `occurences`, and initialize all these values to `0` before use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  your code is fine, because it worked for me, i executed it on a windows seven machine 64, with visual studio c++ 2010.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
std::string input = "And if there's any faster algorithm to deal with a large amount of characters to get the same results i would be thankful ?? How to count the occurrence of the spaces and any ascii characters in a string?";

std::map<char, int> occurrences;

for (std::string::iterator character = input.begin(); character != input.end(); character++)
{
    occurrences[*character] += 1;
}

for (std::map<char, int>::iterator entry = occurrences.begin(); entry != occurrences.end(); entry++)
{
    std::cout << entry->first << '=' << entry->second << std::endl;
}
}
```

Here is the result when executing the above code:

[image]

**Update:**

Here is a new code where iam using a file that contain the above value of the variable `input`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

std::ifstream inputFile("text.txt");
std::string input((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputFile)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());


int main()
{

std::map<char, int> occurrences;

for (std::string::iterator character = input.begin(); character != input.end(); character++)
{
    occurrences[*character] += 1;
}

for (std::map<char, int>::iterator entry = occurrences.begin(); entry != occurrences.end(); entry++)
{
    std::cout << entry->first << '=' << entry->second << std::endl;
}
}
```

we have the same result:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't count spaces from files .. try to read the same string from a file it won't count any spaces

Answer (score 0):

For *really* long strings (over millions of elements), you could split the string up in smaller parts, and pass each part to a thread which handles its small part and adds to its small map, then merge the maps at the end after all threads are done. Otherwise, for string up to thousand or even tens of thousand of characters, it will probably not make much difference, and for strings of less than a few thousand it will probably take more time to set up the threads and merge the maps than your current linear method.

Also unless you want the result sorted, use `std::unordered_map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code counts the characters that are present in the string. Your example, if you wrote `std::string input = "slowly \tmedium \rfast \n";`, would count 3 spaces (32), one tab(8), one cr (13) and one line feed (10).

Of course, if you read the file with something like:

```
std::string input;
...
in >> input;
```

you explicitely ask for blank separated words, so you will find neither spaces nor any other blank (`\t\r\n`).

If you want to count all the characters from a file, you have to use a binary read (`in.read(char *buf, streamsize size)`), on a file opened in binary mode.

Last caveat: if your file uses an multi-byte encoding character set like UTF8, you must be prepared to see the single `é` character as the 2 bytes 0xc3 oxc9...

For the speed, you could first use an array instead of a map for counting characters, and optionnally multi-thread your program for really huge files like Joachim explained.